# Got permission dennied when starting logstash on docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, logstash

I get the following error when trying to start logstash on docker-compose

```
error: open /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml: permission denied
```

my docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: "3"
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.5.1
    ports:
    - "5044:5044"
    expose:
    - "5044"
    volumes:
    - ./config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
    - ./config/pipelines.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
```

the permission of the folder is

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 myuser myuser
```

and on the files inside that folder

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser myuser  91 Mar 10 18:03 logstash.yml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 myuser myuser 295 Mar 10 18:04 pipelines.yml
```

Any ideas on whats wrong with my configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `- ./config/:/usr/share/logstash/config/` and see if it helps in anyway

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `user: root` on your compose file

Comment: I used this to test in windows machine. May be on server I will ask devops person to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

It was SELINUX, setenforce 0 solve the issue